# Expose data as an ODATA API using Mule ESB

Tags: tomcat, mule, odata

I am working on a requirement where in we wanted to expose the Oracle data as an ODATA API using Mule ESB.

I was referring to [this](http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server) article below which uses Apache Olingo libraries. This implementation addresses most part of the solution.

I wanted to know how to run this application in Mule ESB using http End point connectors instead of running on Tomcat server.

As I am a beginner to mule ESB, I dont have much idea on how to create reference to web.xml within the mule flow to pass the requests to the servlets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you can't really  refer to a web.xml or embeed a standard webapp in a mule server, and even if there is a way I will surely not encourage it.

Mule can consume ODATA api with the [ODATA connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/odata-connector) but you cannot really 'create' one in an easy automated way.

In your case the best approach is probally to create the API using the java library you linked on a dedicated tomact and expose the ODATA APi internally and than proxy it trough mule in a simple pass trough.

Now is ODATA is just a choice and not a constraint you may rethink this and just expose your Oracle Data as a restFull API using [RAML](http://raml.org/). Off course just remember that mule shouldn't execute any business logic therefore you shouldn't do direct queries but you can call stored procedures/functions that wrap the business logic.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess using Mule to manually create ODATA producer is not a good option then. Our requirement is to create external objects in Salesforce for the Oracle data using Lightning connect which uses ODATA api. That is why we had to stick with ODATA.

Comment: In this case than you must go for the pure java solution using mule just as pass through proxy. The manual implementation will probably take way more time and be more inefficient, at the end mule is just an ESB and ODATA API are tight coupled to data layer so makes sense to have a ad-hoc service.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree to your comment.  We are also focusing now on the approach that you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome.
Consider giving an upvote or mark answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: I wanted to upvote your comment but currently my account doesn't have enough points to do that.

Comment: You can still upvote or mark as correct the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MuleSoft has an example of using APIKit to generate an OData API from a database.  You can see the example at https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit-odata-example.

This example uses a json data model and APIKit v2.0 to generate flows and a RAML file.  The example already has the database connector configured to make queries to a MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if Mule 3.3.2 version has support for APIKit ?